# Can I change the background color for italic text?

Tags: css, text, background, formatting, italic

I'm not really sure why my italic text has a black bg, but `p { }` is not getting it done and Google just tells me how to make italic text. [full css](https://gist.github.com/CriticalUpdate/702840788399512cda8380200b5badea) // [full html](https://gist.github.com/CriticalUpdate/9dd81f324414abee865ff1507c6ea4bb) *Edit: You'll see I had to specify `background-color` for the headers, or they would have `#000;` bg's as well.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyZtk.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ With reference to your edit "_You'll see..._" there is nothing to see in your post. Please add the code specific to your issue. For guidelines on this please read >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have black background for all the elements even when you don’t specify anything is

> - {
>         background-color: #000;
>         color: #C3CCD3;
>         font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
>         box-sizing: border-box; }

Essentially this means that any element in the HTML should have the above properties.

Also remove any #0b0b0b background color from your css. Since this too is almost like black color.

Making text is possible using the  tag. And the css should then be written for it as

```
i {
    background-color: red; }
```

Comment: Ahh, okay thank you. I do want [dark backgrounds](https://files.catbox.moe/xv4xek.png) but I need my text to all have `#0b0b0b;` as their bg color to match the div boxes. 

I think I should have originally used `body: { background-color: #000; }` for the black website bg.

I had already tried `i` as a tag by itself and it didn't change anything, unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clair at all please provide html with your css not just a screenshot.

All I can see is the * { background-color: #000;} the * stands for Select all elements. So you are basically making eveything with black background.

Also : p { background-color: #0b0b0b; you are making your p elements with black backgrounds since #0b0b0b is also black.

Comment: Whoops, thank you.

`* { }` is #000;, which is the background of the page and not the divs. I had to make `p` a color to match the divs.